# Android bootanimation modification prevention

Tags: android

1. I want to know if there is a way to include your Android bootanimation.zip inside frameworks.apk(or another place not easily accessible) when building from source so that it gets loaded instead of the one in /system/media/bootanimation.zip
   So when a user replaces the bootanimation in /system/media it still loads the default one built into frameworks.apk or some other place that Android can access to stop a user from modifying the bootanimation easily.
2. Or another scenario, a user replaces the bootanimation but then on the next boot Android checks if there is a size, file difference on the bootanimation.zip with a predetermined value(or original file) and if it differs, then it copies a spare bootanimation.zip located somewhere(if possible in frameworks.apk, so users can't get it easily, without decompiling it) and then copies the original bootanimation over the one in /system/media.
   Then on the next boot, the bootanimation will be the original one and users will be baffled why it changed again. Is there a way to write such a script to run on boot or include it in some runtime file in /system/bin perhaps?
3. You can change the default location of the bootanimation.zip, but where would be a good place to hide it and what to rename it too, will also need to keep it small under 5MB and without .zip extension? But this method might be easily discovered.

It is for protecting my work, so others can't take credit for it.
So I just want to make it a little harder for someone that tries to do such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the boot animation somewhere with a different name. And then implement a service in init.rc for copying your boot animation to /system/media after checking the current bootanimation.zip file's checksum. If the user had replaced the bootanimation.zip then the checksum will be different compared to your bootanimation.zip.